# How to save own project file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, project-management

I am working on vs2010, .net 4.0 coding in C# WPF Application.

I am making a tool to process some data. It reads files and adds them to a stack, certain processing is done and some data is saved to the disk too. I need to save the current state of project in a file so I can open it again.

I would like to know how can I make a project file. One thing that I can think of is using xml and add all info to it. What other options are there?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Comment: All the project file is an xml file. It can be generated by creating the xml yourself.  Of course you don't indicate why you need to modify the project file, what you are doing is strange, easier to always update the same file which is already added to the project.

Comment: ok. So I will keep all the relevant information in xml and save it on disk.

Comment: i need to update the file since later i might add more data to the project. i need to keep track of files which are processed, and what operations have already been done on each file.

Comment: You need to modify the Visual Studio project file?  Why don't you just iterate over .xml files in a specific location?

Comment: no no.  i dont change vs project file. I made a tool in vs2010, and that tool needs to make a project file, i was looking how to keep the log of events and save in a project file so open the current state later. I hope i am clear .

Comment: Just generate the project file through code then visual studio solution template is documented well on Microsoft's website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add values to the windows registry
2. Isolated storage
3. A database

I'd personally opt for the xml file, keep it simple